# recursively generating string from tree in python

Tags: python, recursion, tree, networkx, depth-first-search

I am using the networkx library, and I need to convert a tree `T` into a string that represents the tree structure. I am trying to do it recursively, but I cannot get it right.
Nodes of the tree have attributes like `"children"`, which is the number of neighbors of that node, and `"nodeID"` which is a unique integer identifier of that node.
Here's my code:

```
...
import networkx as nx
...

def treeToString(tree, node, string):
    children = tree.nodes[node]["children"] 
    if children == 0:
        # we are on a leaf node
        string = string + str(tree.nodes[node]["nodeID"])
        return string
    else:
        string = string + str(tree.nodes[node]["nodeID"])
        for child in nx.neighbors(tree, node):
            string = string + str(treeToString(tree, child, string))
        return string

stringifiedTree = treeToString(T, root, "")
print(stringifiedTree)
```

The desired output would be, for a tree such as 1-->2, 1-->3, 2-->4, 2-->5, 2-->6 the following: 124563

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: "a string that represents the tree structure" *according to what logic*? Is this some particular sort of *traversal* of the tree? If so, in what order should the tree be traversed? Anyway, one obvious problem here is that writing `string + ...` *does not change* the variable `string`. It *creates a new value*, and then *ignores* that value.

Comment: (Also: "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules." If there are zero children, then you can handle that with the same logic - iterating zero times correctly does nothing. So there shouldn't be a need to separate out the base case logic here.)

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the question

Comment: It is a depth first traversal.

Comment: Okay, and after that correction, what result do you get? If it is still wrong, *how* is it wrong?

Comment: I get that nodes get printed multiple times and I don't understand why.

Comment: Please provide code that creates a small tree and then calls your function, reproducing the problem.